# Protocol with default implementation in swift. Is it interface or abstract class according to OOP?

Tags: swift, oop

According to oop, interface describe methods which inherited classes should implement. It can not contains implementations and hasn't state (variables). In swift we have 'protocol'. If protocol hasn't extension with default implementation it mean that it is interface. But if it has default implementation, is it mean that now it is abstact class or it is interface ?

Comment: Have you considered that it might not fall in either rigid category? Swift calls itself a "protocol-oriented language", so it could be expected that object-oriented concepts don't map 1:1 to Swift concepts.

Comment: A protocol is a protocol; however if you really need to make the distinction, a homogenous protocol (one which make use of `Self` or an associated type; you may not use this directly as a type) with default implementations for some of its blueprints could be _comparable_ to an abstract class in say, C++, which has a few pure virtual methods as well as some virtual methods with default implementations. Protocols are, however, in the end their own entity and concept, and the Apple/Swift devs tend to explicitly distinguish the common Swift paradigm as protocol orientated progr. rather than OOP.

Comment: I would also say that "according to OOP" is a strange statement. "OOP" is not a person or an authority or even a specification, it's just a thing that people made up because it helped them describe successful and unsuccessful approaches to programming. Swift protocols can be used as interfaces in an OO pattern, and can do more. Swift classes can be used as abstract classes, at least conceptually, but have limitations that other languages don't. The important thing with regards to OOP is that there's a close-enough way to express these concepts in the target language.

Comment: @dfri thanks. But if choose Java 8. It now has default implementation in interface. Is it mean that such interface now is abstract class or it is interface? I mean if you create interface with default implementation.

Comment: These are just terms that may hold different meanings in different languages, since different languages naturally differ. I don't use Java myself, so I can't answer as to the latter. In C++, an abstract class is class where at least one method is a pure virtual one; whereas we refer to an interface as an abstract class where all methods are pure virtual ones. In this context, any "default implementation" in a base class would correspond to a non-pure method, in which case such a class would be referred to as an abstract one rather than an interface. But that is C++; regarding Java, ... :)

Comment: If i had to define it in classic terms, it's more like the interface with skeletal implementation pattern.

Comment: @uraimo Got it.  Thanks